# In Javafx how to access object of a component which is under an overridden method? Problem related with TableView

Tags: java, javafx

[This is my following code. Here i wants to access the textField from another class. textField is under overridden method named call().]

```
public class URLCellFactory {

    private static final URLCellFactory urlCellFactory = new URLCellFactory();
//  private final TextField textField = new TextField();

    public Callback<TableColumn<SQLManager, String>, TableCell<SQLManager, String>> cell() {
        Callback<TableColumn<SQLManager, String>, TableCell<SQLManager, String>> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn<SQLManager, String>, TableCell<SQLManager, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<SQLManager, String> call(TableColumn<SQLManager, String> elementsStringTableColumn) {
                        final TableCell<SQLManager, String> cell = new TableCell<SQLManager, String>() {
                            private final TextField textField = new TextField();
                            {
                                urlCellFactory.operateURL(textField);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (empty) {
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                } else {
                                    setGraphic(textField);
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        return cell;
                    }
                };
        return cellFactory;
    }

    public void operateURL(TextField textField) {
        textField.setPromptText("Enter value");
        textField.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Something spoken shit");
            textField.setEditable(false);
            //getURL(textField.getText());
        });
    }

// this function should get access from the textField component. Like: textField.getText();
//    public static String getURL() {
//        return ;
//    }
}
```

[I tried making the textField global, static and also non-static but it corrupt my output.]

```
public class URLCellFactory {

    private static final URLCellFactory urlCellFactory = new URLCellFactory();
    private TextField textField = new TextField();

    public Callback<TableColumn<SQLManager, String>, TableCell<SQLManager, String>> cell() {
        Callback<TableColumn<SQLManager, String>, TableCell<SQLManager, String>> cellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn<SQLManager, String>, TableCell<SQLManager, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell<SQLManager, String> call(TableColumn<SQLManager, String> elementsStringTableColumn) {
                        final TableCell<SQLManager, String> cell = new TableCell<SQLManager, String>() {
                            //private final TextField textField = new TextField();
                            {
                                urlCellFactory.operateURL(textField);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (empty) {
                                    setGraphic(null);
                                } else {
                                    setGraphic(textField);
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        return cell;
                    }
                };
        return cellFactory;
    }

    public void operateURL(TextField textField) {
        textField.setPromptText("Enter value");
        textField.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Something spoken shit");
            textField.setEditable(false);
            //getURL(textField.getText());
        });
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return this.textField.getText();
    }
}
```

[this corrupt my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH21f.png)

[The goal is to access the textField component without corrupting output. As i mentioned earlier i tried every possible ways to make it work but i failed. So, is there any right way to do that properly please provide it would be very helpful. Please also add comment about how your code works if anyone provide any.
Thanks in advance.]

Comment: It looks like you want to access the text (a String value) that is in the TextField, from another class., correct?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about how you want to access it and what you want to do it.

Comment: You should probably be getting the string via the *model* items (i.e., the objects contained in the table's `items` list), not directly via the text field in the cell.

Comment: @prasad_ You are right. Not just string but also every value it contains.

Comment: @HritwikBhowmik What is the purpose of accessing that TextField component in another class? And, how are you accessing it in that other class? Include those details in your post. Ideally, a "Minimal reproducible example" (as mentioned in earlier comments) will clarify your question.

Comment: In general, you can pass a component's reference to another class and use its attributes (like its text) in that class., for example, using a static method. You can possibly try using the Observer and Observable paradigm, so that when there is some change in the text field (observable) it is available in another class (observer). But, this depends what is your use case.

Comment: *"Not just string but also every value it contains"* -> A text field contains a text, i.e. a string.  What other value do you want from a text field?  And how would you make use of those values, whatever they are?  I guess I am just not understanding what you want to do and why.

Comment: @jewelsea Actually i wants to fetch string value from textfield and save it into a database or send to server. That's why i need the string value from textfield. "Every values" means i should be able to call it's functions like getId() or setText() etc (that means all build-in functions it offers) but from another class or fucntion. The idea is to get the text from textfield using another class or function, so that i can save or send it to wherever i want.

Comment: The string value in your text field should be derived from a property in the model for the table rows (the `SQLManager` objects, though that class name at best seems a bad choice). If the user types in the text field and commits the edit, the data in the model should be updated. You can simply retrieve the data from the model. You're just trying to do thing the wrong way here. You should not be retrieving data from UI objects; the UI objects should be representing the data in the model. If you want to get the data, get it from the model.

Comment: @James_D I understand. But can you tell what is the model here? TableView or TableColumn ? And which functions should i use to get the value from the model? Please explain me a bit i am newbie here. Thank you .

Comment: The model is the type you use as the table's items. Given your code is creating cell factories for `TableColumn<SQLManager, String>`, your model is `SQLManager`.

Comment: @Slaw You really solved my problem. Thank you very much for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to get the text directly from the `TextField` of the cell is the wrong approach. The `TableView` API does not provide a way to get the cell at a particular index. Also, there can be more items in the table than there are cells being displayed. Using the text fields to store application state will lead to information loss.

A `TableView` is backed by a "model". The model is a custom class that exposes properties. The class itself represents a single item in the table, displayed in a single row. The properties represent the values to display in each column. Editing the value of a cell should result in the new value being written back to the property of a model instance. You can get the new values via the items when needed.

Cell implementations that allow editing take one of two forms.

1. The cell can enter and exit the editing state. When editing, the UI changes to a control that allows user input. The implementation works via the `startEdit`, `cancelEdit`, and `commitEdit` API of the cell and outside code reacts to the appropriate events.
2. The cell is "always editing". This bypasses the normal editing API and typically makes use of bidirectional bindings.

Your current implementation seems to be an attempt at the second form. But given you also appear to make the text field non-editable in the on-action handler, it seems the first form would be a better fit. And in that case, you can use the built-in [`TextFieldTableCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/22/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html) class instead of writing your own.

Here is an example with a `TableView` that displays `Person` instances which have a first name property and a last name property.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  /*
   * The TableView is set to editable and its two columns have cell factories
   * that return TextFieldTableCell. Cell selection is enabled.
   * 
   * To start editing the property of a person, select the appropriate cell and
   * hit ENTER or click on an already-selected cell. To commit an edit, press
   * ENTER while the TextField has focused. To cancel, press ESC or deselect the
   * cell.
   * 
   * Press the "Add person" button to add a new row to the (initially empty) 
   * table. You can then edit the first and last name of this person.
   * 
   * Press the "Print people" button to print the people in the table's items 
   * list. This will show you that the properties of the Person objects change
   * when you commit edits via the UI.
   */

  private TableView<Person> table;
  private int printCount;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    table = createPersonTable();

    var addPersonBtn = new Button("Add person");
    addPersonBtn.setOnAction(this::handleAddPerson);

    var printPeopleBtn = new Button("Print people");
    printPeopleBtn.setOnAction(this::handlePrintPeople);

    var root = new BorderPane(table);
    root.setTop(new ToolBar(addPersonBtn, printPeopleBtn));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private TableView<Person> createPersonTable() {
    var table = new TableView<Person>();
    table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY_FLEX_LAST_COLUMN);
    table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setEditable(true);

    /*
     * No need to set the onEditCommit handler of the columns because the default handler
     * will set the property for us when the observable returned by the cell-value factory
     * is writable. We are returning StringProperty, which is writable, in both factories below.
     */

    var firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> cdf.getValue().firstNameProperty());
    table.getColumns().add(firstNameCol);

    var lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cdf -> cdf.getValue().lastNameProperty());
    table.getColumns().add(lastNameCol);

    return table;
  }

  private void handleAddPerson(ActionEvent e) {
    e.consume();

    table.getItems().add(new Person("FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME"));

    int row = table.getItems().size() - 1;
    var col = table.getColumns().get(0);
    table.getSelectionModel().select(row, col);
    table.requestFocus();
  }

  private void handlePrintPeople(ActionEvent e) {
    e.consume();

    /*
     * Demonstrates getting the items of the table and querying the properties
     * of those items. Edits committed via the table will be reflected in these items.
     */

    System.out.printf("########## PRINT %02d ##########%n", printCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getItems().size(); i++) {
      var person = table.getItems().get(i);
      System.out.printf(
          "Person %d: First name = '%s', Last name = '%s'%n",
          i, person.getFirstName(), person.getLastName());
    }
    System.out.println();

    printCount++;
  }

  // The model class
  public static class Person {

    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
    public final void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName.set(firstName); }
    public final String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
    public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName; }

    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "lastName");
    public final void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName.set(lastName); }
    public final String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
    public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName; }

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
      setFirstName(firstName);
      setLastName(lastName);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. Problem solved!!